# How to use Device Protected Storage for PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a requirement of **moving Preference from Encryption Storage to Device Protected Storage** so that I will be able to access those preference in user locked state also. For this I have used this method

```
createDeviceProtectedStorageContext().moveSharedPreferencesFrom(this,"preference_filename");
```

But my application also uses PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment for add configuration values to SharedPreference.

**How to tell the PreferenceActivity/PreferenceFragment to use Device Protected Storage instead of using Device Ecryption Storage.**

Answer (score 0):

Call `getPreferenceManager().setStorageDeviceProtected()` in `onCreatePreferences` function in your  `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

```kotlin
class MainPreferenceFr : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        preferenceManager.setStorageDeviceProtected()
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.xxx, rootKey)
    }
}
```